# Combining reflective insulation and conventional (cellulose-based) insulation

Tags: thermal-insulation, reflective-coatings

I'm working with an architect to insulate an apartment (most of a small house) from the 1930s, with limited space. She has hit upon what seems like a good solution for the north-facing courtyard side - which needs less sound insulation: combine a layer of reflective insulation with a layer of conventional insulation (hemp/cotton/linen). You can see some details here: https://forum.buildhub.org.uk/topic/28711-insulating-by-combining-reflective-insulation-cellulose-based-insulation/#comment-431244

Now, this system is new to her and to me. What are some potential issues? (Are we being naive in simply adding the R values of the two layers, say?) I've found some references on combining these two kinds of insulation, but mostly for attics; it does not seem to be very common for walls.

Comment: All answered here (Google search result) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-value_(insulation) and you both need to think about dew point and vapor barrier.

Comment: Sure, you usually add (obviously). I was just wondering whether there was something non-obvious (to me) to be taken into account, since we are talking about two materials whose heat resistance is due to very different reasons (if I understand correctly).

Comment: reflective panels are often combined with fiberglass in the US